# Will animals attack you while you attempt to use wild empathy?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

As the title says, will creatures try to attack you while you are attempting to use wild empathy on them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wild Empathy works like the Diplomacy skill, but on animals.

Generally speaking, if the enemy is not attacking you when you start and is willing to hear you out, they won't attack during diplomatic negotations. So while you are busy with your Wild Empathy, assuming your party stays out of it, most likely the animal will not attack you.

Note the [starting attitude](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#wildEmpathy) of animals:

> The typical domestic animal has a starting attitude of indifferent, while wild animals are usually unfriendly.

Wild animals *usually* are unfriendly, which means they won't outright attack you. Unfriendly is [described](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/diplomacy.htm) as

> Unfriendly | Wishes you ill | Mislead, gossip, avoid, watch suspiciously, insult

However, wild animals are *usually* unfriendly. If you're trying to use Wild Empathy on an animal that is actively stalking you in an attempt to eat you, you will probably still get attacked.

Comment: Thanks for a good answer, i assumed it work like that but wanted to make sure